# How to upload a local Git repository to a New private Online Git Repository

Tags: git, github

One of my online Git repositories got deleted but I have all the commits and works saved on my local Git repository. I want to reupload all the files and folders of my local Git repository onto a new online Git repository. For this, I created a new Online Git repository and then used `git remote add origin <New online Git repository URL>` but it replied me that

> `remote origin already exists`

then I used `git push -u origin master` to push all the commits on my new online repository but it showed an error

> Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

I have used a number of solutions from the internet like using `git pull` commands but it is not working. Drag and drop a folder is also not working in my case.

How can I upload my local repository to a new online Git repository?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to remove the previous origin using `git remote rm origin`. Then try adding your new origin. Hopefully it will work :)